# Can I determine which process sent my window a message?

Tags: winapi, message

I have a window, and I am looking at the messages that are being sent to it using Spy++.  Is it possible to determine which process sent my window a given message, if it indeed was sent from another process?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, Win32 window messages do not contain information about where they were sent from (unless that information is specifically included as part of the message WPARAM and/or LPARAM components).