# how to debug messages on the queue, who sends them? and what is in the queue?

Tags: winapi

The Event Queue is a box that get messages and handles them.

Could you please say , where are the messages that PostMessage and SendMessage are stored? and how to tell who send what message?
What variables can be inspected to get the information?

Comment: I re-tagged this as a winapi question since it is not specific to any particular language. Is this question related to your recent, now deleted question, where you ask about setting a child window to be topmost?

Comment: yes, it is. i need to find the reason why the same component is sending messages to the queue in one window, and not sending in another. i will try to peek at the queue and see if i can find that message.

Comment: It is a popup window that refresh the data, as the uesr type. Lets say its  hovering data.

Comment: `WS_CHILD` and `WS_POPUP` are mutually exclusive (see [Window Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600.aspx)). If you are confused about the terminology, see [Window Features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx) for an introduction.

Comment: OK, so that's the problem. `WM_DRAWITEM` is sent to the parent of the window. Your window has no parent. You'll need to create a window to be that parent if you want an owner draw list box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where are the messages stored?

They are stored in an internal data structure associated with a thread. Note that each thread has zero or one message queues. A message queue is not created automatically for a thread, but created on demand when the thread calls a function that requires a message queue.

Note also that sent messages, those delivered by `SendMessage` do not appear in the queue. Sent messages are synchronous and so not queued.

> How to tell who send what message?

In general that is not possible: [Can I determine which process sent my window a message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185269/can-i-determine-which-process-sent-my-window-a-message)

> What variables can be inspected to get the information?

You cannot. You can use `PeekMessage` to find out whether or not the queue contains a specific message, or find the first message in a given range. But there is no functionality to dump the entire message queue.

Comment: Small correction on sent messages: Sent messages across threads are in fact stored in a queue, and dispatched when one of the message retrieval functions is called, before that message retrieval function returns the first queued message.

Comment: @IInspectable I'd regard that as an implementation detail. They aren't queued in the sense that the are not queued messages is what I meant. They are synchronous.

Comment: The important point is, that sent messages across threads do not directly call the window procedure (as is the case with in-context sent messages). This is not just an implementation detail, because it has consequences for your code. Namely, the receiving thread must call a message retrieval function in order for a cross-thread sent message to get dispatched. A corollary of this is, that the window procedure need not be guarded against multi-threaded accesses.

Comment: @IInspectable I know all of this. But I think that the asker was asking about the message queue.