# How can I detect Mouse Click simulated by SendMessage or PostMessage?

Tags: c++, click, postmessage, setwindowshookex, anti-cheat

I'm working on an anti-clicker in C++. My code works with all Programs that simulate Mouse Clicks, except for Programs which use code like this:

```
NativeMethods.SendMessage((IntPtr)processHandle, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, (IntPtr)1, (IntPtr)LParams(y, x));
```

My code:

```
while (TRUE) {
    struct tagMSG Msg;
    HHOOK Mouse = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, MouseProcces, NULL, NULL);
    while (GetMessage(&Msg, GameMainWindow, 0, 0)) {
        Sleep(5000);
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessageA(&Msg);
    }
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(Mouse);
}
```

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MouseProcces(INT NCode, WPARAM WParam, LPARAM LParam) {
    if (WParam != WM_MOUSEMOVE && WParam != WM_MOUSEWHEEL)
    {
        std::cout << "click" << std::endl;
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, NCode, WParam, LParam);
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9185269/4641116

Comment: You want to check the `LLMHF_INJECTED` and `LLMHF_LOWER_IL_INJECTED ` flag. This can easily be worked around though. In other words, there's no point of doing such detection, if the person injecting the events is savvy enough.

Comment: `WH_MOUSE_LL` can't detect mouse clicks generated by sending/posting window messages.  However, user-generated mouse input is always posted, so you can at least filter out sent messages by using `InSendMessage()` in your mouse message handler. But you won't be able to differentiate posted messages generated by user action vs program code, unless you match up the messages with events from the [Raw Input API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/raw-input) (which is not a trivial task).

Comment: @Brandon those flags only work for mouse input that is simulated using `mouse_event()` or `SendInput()`, not by `SendMessage()`/`PostMessage()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau; ahh sorry. Wasn't aware of such a restriction. You are correct. I had to read the documentation again.

Comment: @RemyLebeau isn't there any hooks that can intercept other WH_MOUSE_LL ?
I just want to detect message sent by Send/PostMessage as for diffrentiation between user or code generated is a minor issue..

Comment: @Jason "*I just want to detect message sent by Send/PostMessage*" - There are simply no hooks for detecting when SM/PM are called, or by whom. You would have to use code injection and detours to detect that. There are `WH_GETMESSAGE` and `WH_CALLWNDPROC` hooks for detecting when window messages are retrieved and processed, but that will not help you in this situation.  When it comes to window messages, you simply can't differentiate between OS-generated messages and simulated messages. If you want to detect a user's real mouse activity, you need a hardware hook (Raw Input or `WH_MOUSE/_LL`).

Comment: @RemyLebea Do you mean by injection something like WH_MOUSE ?

Comment: @Jason No, I mean actually injecting your own code into other people's processes, such as by putting your code into a DLL and then using `CreateRemoteThread()` or `AppInit_Dlls` or similar to load that DLL into another process. The DLL can then detour any API function it wants to intercept.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Can you tell me Which Api Function I have to Detour,
I'm already Detouring some Kernel Functions [writeprocessmemory-loadlibraryA] to help me in foreign modules detection

Comment: @Jason to detect simulated mouse/keyboard window messages, you would have to inject code into every running process and have that code detour all of the `SendMessage...()` and `PostMessage()` functions, and then you can look at the parameters they are being passed.